# Is userHeight still a thing in A-Frame version 0.9.2?

Tags: aframe

I'm getting a warning saying "Unknown property `userHeight` for component/system `camera`.".  And it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

No, [it has been removed](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/camera.html#properties). Modify the camera position to set the user height in 2D mode (in VR mode it will be overridden by the headset position):

```
<a-entity camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls></a-entity>
```

To place the user in the scene in both 2D and VR use a [camera rig](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/camera.html#examples):

```
<a-entity id="rig" position="25 10 0">
 <a-entity id="camera" camera look-controls></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```